# How to find new values from json file in btc-e api

Tags: btce

Hello i cannot find solution on this issue:

On address https://btc-e.com/api/2/btc_usd/depth is json list from btc-e api.
I'm searching for solution parse only new values from json list and store to the database.
There isn't any identifier, but only values.
I'm using MySQL + PHP.
Is there any solution to solve this?

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by "New values" ?

Comment: I mean values not in previous check, only the new items from last checking. For example: 1st cron = 512,457,845 2nd cron = 512,457,201,845 I need 201 value

Comment: Are you asking how to parse JSON in PHP?

Comment: No. I'm asking how detect new values in json file.

Comment: This don't look possible with the web-service call you have provided

Comment: Thank you, it seems you have best answer. There is no solution.